# How to build dynamic List

Tags: .net, list, web-services, class

I'm new to lists and I can not find the right way to build a (dynamic) list. The list is used as the return from a Web-service.

I normally use a simple class to build my list like:

```
Public Class Book
    Public ID As String
    Public Book As String
    Public Author As String
End Class

Dim dtBooks = New DataTable()
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From theBooks", myConn)
    da.Fill(dtBooks)
End Using

Dim Books As List(Of Book) = New List(Of Book)
For Each aBook As DataRow In Books.Rows
    Dim nBook As Book = New Book()
    With nBook
        .ID = aBook("ID")
        .Author = aBook("Author")
        .Book = aBook("Name")
    End With
    Books.Add(nBook)
Next

Return New With {.data = Books, .success = True, .message = "OK"}
```

In most cases I know the names of the columns from the database, so I can use a class like the example above, but in some cases I do not know the names of the columns in the database.

I did several test with dictionaties (Dim strResultList As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))), but it gave me not the same result.

Can some one help me and put me on the right track how I can make a list (like Books) bases on the result of a simple query which can be used as the return-value in a web-service?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Arno.